# I Paid but No Download :/

Tags: elementary-website, download

I paid and no download happened - how can I fix this? I followed the basic capture routine of Open OS that you can't download without a Credit Card.

Comment: elementary OS is free software. You can just enter 0$ and download it for free.

Comment: Could you please modify your question and describe more detailed how did you tried to download? Which Browser? From which OS? Have you any ad-block extensions installed?

Comment: Browser and Version and OS and Version? As far as we know, no ad-blocker blocks our download, but disabling them on elementary.io would be a good start.

Comment: I have tried to download it three times and it fails at about 95% with no helpful error message, just a failure message. There is 25 gigs left on the hard drive, so it is not running out of space for the download. Trying to get 64bit version. Now I can't even get a choice of download site, it just takes me back to start over again. This is getting tiresome. I paid for the software, but there isn't even a valid support desk to help me. Please advise.

Answer (score 11):

You are of course *not* required to pay. If you did the devs will surely appreciate it though.

Your question gives almost no details on what problem you are facing. If you did not see the window with the links to download the torrent files, you can just go to https://elementary.io, enter $0 and click the "Download" button.

Answer (score 1):

It's seems like u have problem with your Internet. I download the iso with very bad WiFi signal and keep disconnecting after for awhile, but i can connect again and resume download until 100% and not corrupted. Maybe u better download with torrent method

Thank you